# JQuery tmpl is not working as expected in my if block

Tags: json, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I'm trying to interrogate a string value using JQuery.tmpl() from within an `{{if}}` block and it's not working for some reason.

I'm using KnockoutJS to render a dashboard with many different types of panels. Each panel has a `Type` property that will tell me which type of panel it is. So, here is a (very simple) concept of what my data might look like:

```
var data = {"Panels": [
  {"Type": "A", ... },
  {"Type": "B", ... },
  {"Type": "C", ... },
]};
```

Here is a template that will render different div tags depending on the `Type`:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
   {{if Type == "A"}}
     <div>A</div>

   {{else Type == "B"}}
     <div>B</div>

   {{else Type == "C"}}
     <div>C</div>

   {{else}}
     <div>'${Type}' is invalid!</div>

   {{/if}}
</script>
```

However, I *always* get output like this:

```
<div>'A' is invalid!</div>
<div>'B' is invalid!</div>
<div>'C' is invalid!</div>
```

How can I check a string property (ie. `Type`) using an `{{if ..}}` block?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working copy of your sample in JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/cnzeg/

Is there anything different about my sample from what you are trying?

Only other thing that can cause a problem in IE is the trailing comma on your Panels array here:

```
var data = {"Panels": [
  {"Type": "A", ... },
  {"Type": "B", ... },
  {"Type": "C", ... }*,*
]};
```

Wouldn't cause the problem that you are seeing though and was likely not in your actual code.

Comment: Thank you for this. I updated the solution to show the problem that I think I'm having: http://jsfiddle.net/TrailHacker/cnzeg/2/

Comment: I just wanted to update with another comment stating that I'm accepting this as my answer, and need to investigate my problem further. You proved to me that my problem is something else in my code. :) Thanks again!!

Comment: Look at this one: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/zRqrw/ .  It seems like the path to the mapping plugin was not right on your fiddle, so I updated it.  The main change then was that after going through the mapping plugin everything with be observable, so you need to reference Type as a function in your code like Type().  Hope this helps.